# Como posso remover o "Inspecionar elemento" do Chromium portable

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, google-chrome-extensão

Eu estou criando uma aplicação PHP que irá rodar exclusivamente com o Chromium, isto vem do projeto ***php desktop chromium v1*** que pode ser conferido [aqui.](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop-chromium/)

Meu projeto é um programa simples de loja rodando em localhost, e abre dentro deste Chromium, eu gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de remover a opção "inspecionar elemento" do navegador, pelo que li o Chromium permite uma alta gama de alterações direto por `.ini`, e queria saber se há uma forma de fazer isso e como se faz se possível.
A Remoção não é algo crítico, mas se tivesse como fazer ficaria feliz em saber como.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível fazer isto editando o arquivo de [*preferência do usuário*](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences).

1. Vá na pasta do *php desktop chromium v1* e navegue até: *`phpdesktop-chromium_v1`* ⇢ *`chromium`* ⇢ *`Data`* ⇢ *`Profiles`*.
2. Vá até a pasta de preferência do usuário, neste caso a pasta *`Default`*.
3. Abra o arquivo *`Preferences`* com um editor de texto.
4. Procure pela palavra *devtools* usando o *Pesquisar* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).
5. Deve aparecer algo parecido com isto:

   ```all
   "devtools": {
       "split_location": 214
    },
   ```

   Deixe está seção assim:

   ```all
   "devtools": {
      "disabled": true, "split_location": 214
   },
   ```
6. Salve o arquivo.
7. Abra o navegador novamente e veja se funcionou.

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ótimo @qmechanik, obrigado mais uma vez! ;)